# How can I execute an IronRuby script from Rails 3.0.7 on Windows?

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, ironruby

I have a project in Ruby 1.9.2 using Rails 3.0.7 on Windows in which I would like to be able to run both Ruby and IronRuby scripts.  When I attempt to call an IronRuby script (ex. - "ir example.rb") using system() or backticks, it seems as though the script is not being run in IronRuby.  I have some .dll files required and when the script is being run I am receiving a LoadError saying that there is a missing helper file example.dll.rb.  Does anyone have any information regarding running an IronRuby script from Rails3?  Thanks!

Comment: Made some progress on this calling the IronRuby scripts with rspec rather than ir (this is a test suite for both rails and .NET applications), the .dll Load Error is no longer an issue, but rspec is running in Ruby instead of IronRuby.  Not sure how get rspec to run in IronRuby instead of in Ruby from Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the call to run the IronRuby script, include the path to your IronRuby bin.. ex: "system('C:\IronRuby\bin\rspec example_spec.rb')"